# How to resolve Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: _ZCMain_main_closure?

Tags: macos, haskell, cabal

I built a haskell cabal app on my Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.3. But when I try to run it using

```
ghc webrtc-vad.cabal
```

I get the error

> file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x6E 0x61 0x6D 0x65 0x3A
>   0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 ) which is not
>   the architecture being linked (x86_64): webrtc-vad.cabal ... Undefined
>   symbols for architecture x86_64:   "_ZCMain_main_closure"

The makefile looks like this:

```
name:                webrtc-vad
version:             0.1.0.2
synopsis:            Easy voice activity detection
description:         A simple library wrapping WebRTC's voice activity detection engine.
license:             MIT
license-file:        LICENSE
author:              Patrick Chilton
maintainer:          chpatrick@gmail.com
-- copyright:           
category:            Sound
build-type:          Simple
-- extra-source-files:  
cabal-version:       >=1.10
extra-source-files:
  src/cbits/webrtc/*.h
  src/cbits/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/*.h
  src/cbits/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/include/*.h
  src/cbits/webrtc/common_audio/vad/*.h
  src/cbits/webrtc/common_audio/vad/include/*.h
  src/cbits/webrtc/system_wrappers/interface/*.h

source-repository head
  type:                git
  location:            https://github.com/chpatrick/haskell-webrtc-vad.git

library
  exposed-modules:     Sound.VAD.WebRTC
  -- other-modules:       
  other-extensions:    ForeignFunctionInterface
  build-depends:       base >=4.6 && <4.9, vector >= 0.11.0.0, primitive >= 0.6
  hs-source-dirs:      src
  build-tools:         hsc2hs
  default-language:    Haskell2010
  include-dirs:        src/cbits
  cc-options:          -DWEBRTC_POSIX -fPIC -m64
  ghc-options:         -Wall
  c-sources:
    src/cbits/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/downsample_fast.c
    src/cbits/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/min_max_operations.c
    src/cbits/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/cross_correlation.c
    src/cbits/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/vector_scaling_operations.c
    src/cbits/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/spl_init.c
    src/cbits/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/resample_48khz.c
    src/cbits/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/resample_by_2_internal.c
    src/cbits/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/resample_fractional.c
    src/cbits/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/division_operations.c
    src/cbits/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/energy.c
    src/cbits/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/complex_bit_reverse.c
    src/cbits/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/complex_fft.c
    src/cbits/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/get_scaling_square.c
    src/cbits/webrtc/common_audio/signal_processing/real_fft.c
    src/cbits/webrtc/common_audio/vad/webrtc_vad.c
    src/cbits/webrtc/common_audio/vad/vad_core.c
    src/cbits/webrtc/common_audio/vad/vad_gmm.c
    src/cbits/webrtc/common_audio/vad/vad_filterbank.c
    src/cbits/webrtc/common_audio/vad/vad_sp.c
```

How can I compile the app correctly for my platform?

Comment: What command are you running `ghc webrtc-vad.cabal` doesn't make sense to me. You `cabal build` or `cabal install` a package. That file isn't a makefile btw, its a cabal file. And the package isn't an application, its just a library that can be invoked from other haskell code.

Answer (score 1):

Try running `cabal install webrtc-vad` instead.